# Launch terminated in cudaDeviceSynchronize after timeout

Tags: cuda, gpu

I try to run a simple program with 3 dimensional grid but for some reason when I launch it with cuda-memcheck it just gets stuck, and after the timeout it's terminated. The problem has nothing to do with a short timeout cause I changed it just for this manner to 60 seconds.

The code I run has a grid of 45x1575x1575 and it runs an empty `__global__` function. My compute capability is 2.1 and I compile with the flag `-maxrregcount=24` to limit the number of registers the device functions can use (saw in some other program of mine that it gives the best results with the occupancy calculator)

Here's my code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void stam(int a){

}

int main()
{


    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        return;
    }

    dim3 gridSize(45,1575,1575);
    stam<<<gridSize,224>>>(4);
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // This function gets stuck
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!!");
        return;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Isn't the max grid size 65535x65535x65535? What is the problem in here?

Edit: it only crashes when I compile it with the -G flag. Otherwise it's just slow, but it doesn't exceed the 60 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is simply taking too long (yes, longer than 60 seconds) to run.

Even though your kernel "does nothing" it still represents a `__global__` function call.  To facilitate it, a fair amount of preamble code gets generated by the compiler.  Normally the compiler would optimize much of that preamble code away, since your function does nothing (e.g. it does nothing with the variable passed to it, which the preamble code makes available to each thread.)  However when you pass the `-G` switch, you eliminate nearly all compiler optimizations.  You can get a sense of the size of the code that is *actually running* for each threadblock, by taking your executable and [inspecting the code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#abstract) with `cuobjdump -sass ...`.

Secondly, running code with `cuda-memcheck` usually increases execution time.  The `cuda-memcheck` executive adjusts the order and reduces the rate at which threadblocks get executed, so it can do full analysis of the memory access pattern of each threadblock, among other things.

The net effect is that your empty kernel call, in part due to the very large grid (over 100 million threadblocks need to be processed), is taking longer than 60 seconds to execute.  If you want to verify this, increase your TDR timeout to 5 minutes or 10 minutes, and eventually you will see the program return normally.

In my case, with `-G` and `cuda-memcheck` your program takes about 30 seconds to run on  a Quadro5000 GPU, which has 11 SMs.  Your cc2.1 GPU may have around 2 SMs, and so will run even slower than mine.  If I compile without the `-G` switch, the runtime drops to about 2 seconds.  If I compile with the `-G` switch, but run without `cuda-memcheck`, it takes about 4 seconds.  If I eliminate the `int a` parameter from the kernel (which drastically reduces the preamble code), I can compile with `-G` and run with `cuda-memcheck` and it only takes 2 seconds.

Kernel machine code with `-G` and `int a` parameter:

```
            Function : _Z4stami
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
    /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];            /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
    /*0008*/         ISUB R1, R1, 0x8;                 /* 0x4800c00020105d03 */
    /*0010*/         S2R R0, SR_LMEMHIOFF;             /* 0x2c000000dc001c04 */
    /*0018*/         ISETP.GE.AND P0, PT, R1, R0, PT;  /* 0x1b0e00000011dc23 */
    /*0020*/     @P0 BRA 0x30;                         /* 0x40000000200001e7 */
    /*0028*/         BPT.TRAP;                         /* 0xd00000000000c007 */
    /*0030*/         IADD R0, R1, RZ;                  /* 0x48000000fc101c03 */
    /*0038*/         MOV R2, R0;                       /* 0x2800000000009de4 */
    /*0040*/         MOV R3, RZ;                       /* 0x28000000fc00dde4 */
    /*0048*/         MOV R2, R2;                       /* 0x2800000008009de4 */
    /*0050*/         MOV R3, R3;                       /* 0x280000000c00dde4 */
    /*0058*/         MOV R4, c[0x0][0x4];              /* 0x2800400010011de4 */
    /*0060*/         MOV R5, RZ;                       /* 0x28000000fc015de4 */
    /*0068*/         IADD R2.CC, R2, R4;               /* 0x4801000010209c03 */
    /*0070*/         IADD.X R3, R3, R5;                /* 0x480000001430dc43 */
    /*0078*/         MOV32I R0, 0x20;                  /* 0x1800000080001de2 */
    /*0080*/         LDC R0, c[0x0][R0];               /* 0x1400000000001c86 */
    /*0088*/         IADD R2.CC, R2, RZ;               /* 0x48010000fc209c03 */
    /*0090*/         IADD.X R3, R3, RZ;                /* 0x48000000fc30dc43 */
    /*0098*/         MOV R2, R2;                       /* 0x2800000008009de4 */
    /*00a0*/         MOV R3, R3;                       /* 0x280000000c00dde4 */
    /*00a8*/         ST.E [R2], R0;                    /* 0x9400000000201c85 */
    /*00b0*/         BRA 0xc8;                         /* 0x4000000040001de7 */
    /*00b8*/         EXIT;                             /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    /*00c0*/         EXIT;                             /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    /*00c8*/         EXIT;                             /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    /*00d0*/         EXIT;                             /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
            .........................
```

Kernel machine code with `-G` but without `int a` parameter:

```
            Function : _Z4stamv
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
    /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];  /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
    /*0008*/         BRA 0x20;               /* 0x4000000040001de7 */
    /*0010*/         EXIT;                   /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    /*0018*/         EXIT;                   /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    /*0020*/         EXIT;                   /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    /*0028*/         EXIT;                   /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
            .........................
```

Comment: As an additional test, I ran your code on a Quadro1000M (a cc2.1 GPU with 2 SMs) and the execution time with `-G` was 6.5 seconds.  With `cuda-memcheck` and `-G` the execution time was 75 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very complete answer! I really didn't think about this possibility because the limit of the grid is 65535x65535x65535. I will no longer do memcheck after compiling with -G flag.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code with no problems on a C2050 (capability 2.0) under both cuda-memcheck and cuda-gdb. This suggests the problem is more likely related to your card/setup than the code itself.

If you were exceeding capability, you should get a launch error code, not a hang (you can check max sizes using deviceQuery SDK code if you're unsure).

It may be that cuda-memcheck is trying to gain exclusive control of the GPU, and is timing out as something else is using it [e.g. your X server] - does cuda-gdb work any better, do these tools work for other codes?

Comment: Yup, the tool works for other codes with one dimensional grid (didn't check many examples of 3d grids).. Also I forgot to mention I have everything up to date. This is really weird :( How can I check if something else is using the GPU?